# In Magit: fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: magit

For some repositories at work I get the following message when I try to push my commits:

```
GitError! Could not read from remote repository.  [Type `$' for details]
```

The details read:

```
128 C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git.exe … "push" "-v" "origin" "master:refs/heads/master"
Pushing to ssh://git@XXX.git

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any idea what the problem could be?
Running the above git command from a git-bash (minus those tripple-dots) also works. In fact, that's my workaround. Compose the commit with magit and just type git push in a git-bash.
Pushing to github.com repository on the same machine works from magit.

Comment: Type `TAB` on the `128...` line to actually see the details.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question accordingly. I'm mainly puzzled by the fact that git-bash doesn't give me such an error.

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Pushing-with-Magit-from-Windows

Comment: Since you are pushing to `ssh://...`, you must be using SSH keys to authenticate against the repository. I'd start by making sure that `git-bash` expands `$HOME` to the same directory as `M-x getenv HOME`. Or, perhaps, you are running an `ssh-agent` program that manages the keys for you, but it runs in the `git-bash` session, and not in Emacs (so you would need to start `ssh-agent` in Emacs too).

Comment: @wvxvw: That was the perfect hint! Emacs and git-bash were seeing different HOME variables. The easiest way was creating a symlink to .ssh so that emacs sees it. Problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that emacs was seeing a different $HOME variable than git-bash and could therefore not find the ssh-keys. Thanks to @wvxvw for pointing me in the right direction. After creating a symlink everything works now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message until moments ago. I had to install the package `ssh-agency`. A solution that is also documented in [the link provided](https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Pushing-with-Magit-from-Windows) by @npostavs

In spacemacs you do that by adding it to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`.

Comment: Can you explain more how you did it? I still have the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Working with remotes used to be fine until Emacs was updated to 26.3 from 26.2 on my Fedora 30 computer. The solution is to set the variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` for Emacs:

1. Check the value of this variable on your system

   ```
   $ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
   ```
2. Set it from Emacs with value from above. For me it's "/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh".

   ```
   M-x setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK RET /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
   ```

Source: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/10969

Comment: Thanks. Turns out my shell's SSH_AUTH_SOCK differed from that in Emacs. Setting it in my init.el solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. For me, the `git` cli was working fine from the terminal but failed to work inside Emacs. I opened an [interactive shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html) and ran the same command and the error was much clear:

```
sibi { ~/github/dotfiles }-> git fetch origin
Bad owner or permissions on /home/sibi/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Fixing it was much simpler after that:

```
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

And after that all the magit operations start working as usual.